# Alone or by yourself?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is there any slight difference between these two sentences?

- You cannot drink it alone.
  and
- You cannot drink it by yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, a slight difference, more in usage than in grammar terms.

> You cannot drink it alone.

means wanting to drink with other people around. More common would be:

> You cannot drink alone.

For example:

> (Someone walks into the bar and wants to join you, and insists) You cannot drink alone.

as for

> You cannot drink it by yourself.

means you need someone's help to finish the drink. For example:

> That is a large bottle of wine. You cannot drink it by yourself.

Of course then two people are involved so you are not alone. In any case, it is ambiguous without context.

Comment: +1. For the main distinction here. Though **by yourself** can also mean, "without company".  *Why are you sitting here off in the corner by yourself?*

Comment: I think the *it* in the first sentence is critical. With *it*, it does mean pretty much the same as "by yourself," in my opinion.

Comment: @Ringo That is how I read it in my mind. In straight grammar, there may be no difference.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Sure, but that is changing the context. For this question, the only context I can assume is drinking some (probably alcoholic) liquid. Possibly this question should be closed for lacking more specific context.

Comment: @user3169: To be sure, context is key. Transitive/intransitive makes all the difference.

Comment: Funny, I would have split the difference the other way.

Answer (score 7):

Both of these statements carry two meanings which are the same.  How they are to be understood depends on the context that they're used in.

They could mean:

- You cannot drink it without another person present.
- You cannot drink it without sharing it with another person.

**You cannot drink it alone** can also have a third meaning:

- You cannot drink it without eating or drinking something else at the same time.

Comment: Well done noticing the third meaning. It might be interesting to note that the third meaning could also be expressed by "you cannot drink it by itself" — that is, it comes up because it's ambiguous whether "alone" applies to the subject or the object in this case.

Comment: @MvLog "You can't eat/drink it by itself" it might be grammatically "wrong", but it's often used in British English, and most people will understand exactly what it means. It's also completely unambiguous, unlike "You can't eat/drink it alone". The alternative meaning would be expressed as "You can't eat/drink it by *oneself*" of course.

Comment: @MvLog "you cannot drink it by itself" isn't wrong in any way. There's no lack of a verb, no lack of a subject, and no problem using "it".

Comment: Let's see [what the gurus say about it.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406611/you-cannot-drink-it-by-itself)

Comment: "You can't eat/drink it by itself" sounds fine in American English, too. In fact, "You should not take X by itself" is a common drug warning, and such warnings need to be absolutely clear to avoid dangerous consequences.